# YouCompleteMe with cygwin

Tags: plugin-you-complete-me, cygwin

I installed YouCompleteMe (`--clang-completer`), but cannot use it. On start I see a message

```
The ycmd server SHUT DOWN (restart with ':YcmRestartServer'). Unexpected exit code -11. Use the ':YcmToggleLogs
' command to check the logs.
```

- `:YcmRestartServer`. I've got a message `Restarting ycmd server...` and nothing happens. The message is showed a long time and disappeared just when I input `:`. YCM still doesn't work.
- `:YcmDiags` shows message `Native filetype completion not supported for current file, cannot force recompilation.` This is c++ `hello world` application (`*.cpp` or `*.cxx`)
- `:YcmDebugInfo` shows a message

  ```
   Printing YouCompleteMe debug information...
   -- Client logfile: /tmp/ycm_642rzu.log
   -- Server errored, no debug info from server
   -- Server running at: http://127.0.0.1:56271
   -- Server process ID: 10184
   -- Server logfiles:
   --   /tmp/ycmd_56271_stdout_6djrrG.log
   --   /tmp/ycmd_56271_stderr_3G61Dj.log
  ```

  The last two logs are empty files. 
  File `/tmp/ycm_642rzu.log` includes a lot of `ConnectTimeout` errors similar to each other like the following:

  ```
   2017-02-26 22:47:12,994 - ERROR - Unable to connect to server
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/home/loom/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/autoload/../python/ycm/client/base_request.py", line 196, in HandleServerException
       yield
     File "/home/loom/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/autoload/../python/ycm/youcompleteme.py", line 350, in ServerBecomesReady
       'ready' )
     File "/home/loom/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/autoload/../python/ycm/client/base_request.py", line 74, in GetDataFromHandler
       timeout ) )
     File "/home/loom/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/autoload/../python/ycm/client/base_request.py", line 162, in JsonFromFuture
       response = future.result()
     File "/home/loom/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/pythonfutures/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 404, in result
       return self.__get_result()
     File "/home/loom/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/pythonfutures/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 356, in __get_result
       raise self._exception
   ConnectTimeout: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=56271): Max retries exceeded with url: /ready (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x6fffeef4810>, 'Connection to 127.0.0.1 timed out. (connect timeout=0.01)'))
  ```

How can I fix YCM?